# Enlongate vector to match distribution of ordered natural numbers in r

Tags: r, vector

Can I somehow enlongate a vector  of characters in r so that it matches a distribution of natural numbers? If I have

```
vector1 <- c("h1", "h2", "h3", "h4", "h5")
```

and also

```
vector2 <- c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5)
```

I'd like to know if theres a method to get

```
 desiredvector <- c("h1", "h1", "h2", "h2", "h2", "h3", "h4", "h4", "h4", "h4", "h5")
```

Thanks for any answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The square bracket operator [] accesses the object on its left by index (starting at 1). Your `vector2` contains indices into `vector1` repeated the number of times that you want the value at that index. This is exactly what the [] operator does.

```
vector1 <- c("h1", "h2", "h3", "h4", "h5")
vector2 <- c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5)
desiredvector <- vector1[vector2]

desiredvector
# [1] "h1" "h1" "h2" "h2" "h2" "h3" "h4" "h4" "h4" "h4" "h5"
```